# Processing Files Using Threads in .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have requirement where i need process multiple files in parallel, so i have chosen threads for this

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputFilePath))
{
   FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
   if (!(file.ToUpper().Contains("ENCODING") || file.Contains("HEADERS")))
   {
       workerThreads[io] = new Thread(() => ProcessSingleFile(file, log, f));
       workerThreads[io].Name = "Thread " + file;
   }
   io++;
}
foreach (var worker in workerThreads)
{
    worker.Start();
}
_pool.Release(MaxNumberOfProcessors);
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var worker in workerThreads)
{
    worker.Join();
}
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Now I call the method **ProcessSingleFile(file, log, f)**, which process *(accoriding to business)* the file and writes processed file into another directory using **StreamWriter** and **StreamReader**.

Now the issue is say if i have 15 files its processing them randomly, i.e sometimes i find 10 (this number is random)files in output directory , sometimes 15(processing all).

I'm using semaphore to have MaxNumber of threads using below functions.

```
    private static Semaphore _pool = new Semaphore(0, MaxNumberOfProcessors);   
   _pool.WaitOne();
   _pool.Release();
```

Can anyone please let me know why its behaving randomly?

Comment: You should consider not using regular threads for this kind of task and the problem is probably that `file` changes due to lambdas and scoping in foreach loops. Try to assign `file` to another variable.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided a simple example we could actually test. Aside from that, you should probably use Tasks instead of threads. Also, regarding processing files in parallel, you should probably do all the I/O sequentially, then farm out the work from some in memory data structure.

Comment: Hi Henk, tried Parallel.ForEach(), same issue. Cant use this because i have files having size upto 28GB (for a single file)

Comment: @Bauss : tried you approach, seems to be not working

Comment: @Henk, sorry i'm not able understand what Bauss means, can you please explain ?

Comment: @Henk: I did this    var a = file;
                     var b = log;
                     var c = f;
                     workerThreads[io] = new Thread(() => ProcessSingleFile(a, b, c));
                     workerThreads[io].Name = "Thread " + file;

                 }, still the same issue. are you sure its the correct diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an example where thread handling via Tasks are easier to use then doing it yourself.

The Task class and the Task`<TResult`> class can be found in namespace System.Threading.Tasks.

A Task is most easily created and started using. After a task is started you can do other things, and when you need the results of the task, wait until it is finished.

```
var myTask = Task.Run( () => MyFunction(myParameters);
// while the task is running do other useful things
// like starting even more tasks
// after a while you need the result
Task.Wait(myTask);
// or if my function returns a TResult:
TResult result = Task.Wait(myTask);
```

To wait until several tasks are finished:

```
Task.WaitAll(severalTasks);
```

So in your example your code would be like:

(btw: in your example you suddenly have an object file. I assume this is the file name)

```
public void ProcessFiles(string inputFilePath)
{
    DirecotryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputFilePath);
    if (!dir.Exsists)
    {
        ReportProblem(...);
        return;
    }

    var filesToProcess = dir.EnumerateFiles()
        .Where(fileInfo => IsFileNameAcceptable(fileInfo.Name);
    var runningTasks = filesToProcess
        .Select(fileToProcess => Task.Run( () => ProcessSingleFile(file.Name, log, f))
        .ToArray();
    // note: linq uses deferred execution.
    // ToArray is used to make sure the tasks are really started
    // while the tasks are running you can do other things
    // after a while wait for the tasks to finish:
    runningTasks.WaitAll();
}

private bool IsFileNameAcceptable(string fileName)
{
   return !(fileName.ToUpper().Contains("ENCODING") || fileName.Contains("HEADERS"));
   // or did you mean:
   var upperFileName = fileName.ToUpper();
   return !upperFileName.Contains("ENCODING")
       && !upperFileNmae.Contains("HEADERS");
}
```

Finally: Some people prefer to start a Task using Task.Factory.StartNew()
For the difference see
[Task.Run versus Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Comment: Watch out: Task.Run is not necessarily better than using dedicated threads. Using threads from the thread pool for an IO operation or any non-trivial operation that can block can lead to thread-starvation deadlocks, because the thread pool is a limited shared resource, like a global semaphore, shared by all libraries. It is often better to use dedicated threads.

Answer (score 0):

The ressources of HD  are not extensible as yours threads ...

You should use the TPL (Parralele Library) for sending job per CPU not overcharging the complete system. In this maner you will have a maximum thread number limited by your CPU (usually 2 or 4) and you will not surcharge the I/O.